# When I search C and linux-kernel, I end up with lots of C# developers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, search

That simply should not happen. Any remedies?

Comment: What? Where? -------

Comment: [No repro](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+linux-kernel). Link to your search? Or are you talking about Careers?

Comment: Do you mean on SO search? careers search? More info needed, we cant' make bricks without clay.

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce this. When searching for `[c] [linux-kernel]`, the [results are as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+linux-kernel).

Perhaps, take a look at the [search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search) to get an understanding of how to narrow down your results. Using a combination of the advanced options will quickly bring what you're looking for right to the top of the results.

I suspect that you didn't use a tag based search, which is probably why you got such mixed results.

For instance, a search for questions tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c) [linux-kernel](/questions/tagged/linux-kernel) containing posts with the phrase 'epoll' in the body could be expressed as `[c] [linux-kernel]  body:"epoll"`.

Comment: even searching for "c linux-kernel" without the quotes produces reasonable results ... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+linux-kernel